# How do Killstreaks affect Mediguns?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-medic

Mediguns such as the default Medigun, the Kritzkrieg, the Quick-Fix and the Vaccinator can have Killstreak Kits attached to them. This includes Basic, Specialized and Professional Killstreak Kits.

For any other weapon, these work as follows:

- **Basic** Killstreak Kits track how many kills you got with said weapon before you die. This included a server-wide message when you hit certain thresholds, such as 20 kills, and messages when you are killed after such a threshold.
- **Specialized** Killstreak Kits do everything a Basic Killstreak Kit does, as well as giving your weapon a colored sheen, which intensifies as your killstreak increases.
- **Professional** Killstreak Kits do everything a Specialized Killstreak Kit does, as well as giving you an unusual eye effect once you reach a killstreak of 5. This unusal effect intensifies as your killstreak increses.

However, since the Medigun can not deal any damage, it can not ever kill anybody. The only possibility for it to "kill" is to assist someone by healing them while they get a kill. Does this count as a "kill" in terms of a killstreak for the Mediguns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, you've got it. When a medic gets an assist while using a medigun, that assist will be be counted as a kill for the purposes of the killstreak counter. Mediguns work exactly the same as normal killstreak weapons which gain effects upon hitting kill threshholds, except that the counter is increased by getting assists.

Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxSuX-ezLa8) showing the medic getting a killstreak while his heal target kills enemies. Look for the streak counter in the bottom-left. When the medic gets to 10 assists, he gets the same kind of server-wide message anyone else with a ten killstreak would get.